UIbutton not responding consistently to touch event
I placed my UI button inside stack view of storyboard in UIKit App. and I enabled user interaction to both stack view and button. My button width and height are 20,20. I am using this UIbutton for checkbox sometimes it is responsive and sometimes I have to click multiple times. I tried increasing the size of the box but no luck.when I use tip of my nail it works and if I use my entire finger it won't work. I guess when my finger touches both stackview and button it won't work

Is the button not receiving the touch? Or, is there logic problems with your code so it appears the button was not tapped? A 20x20 button can be difficult to tap to begin with... in general, for something like a "checkbox" button, make the button larger than the checkbox image.

I need to click multiple times on the button. There is no other logical problem

OK -- again, a 20x20 button can be difficult to tap. Quick test, and I can successfully tap a 20x20 button repeatedly, but yes, it is tough to get the finger tap on the right spot. It has nothing to do with the button being in a stack view. Try using your 20x20 "checkbox button" by itself ... I bet you'll have the same difficulty.

Yes can't agree more, I will increase button size and check

@DonMag Add your comment as answer, I will accept it

Posting this answer, as per the OP's comments...
The issue is unrelated to the button being in a stack view -- the problem, is the size of the button.
Apple's Human Interface Guidelines states:

As a general rule, a button needs a hit region of at least 44x44 pt

That is not a requirement, but as you've seen it can be very tough to consistently tap a 20x20 button.
Options for a "checkbox button" could include:

larger button to begin with
larger button frame, with a checkbox image (smaller than the frame)
subclassing and using hitTest(_:with:) to expand the touch area
using a UI element other than a UIButton and handling the touches

Up to you to decide which approach fits best with your overall design / UI goals.

Edit - in response to comment...
Searching for swift custom checkbox button returns lots of results.
If you want to look at a very simple example, here is some sample code:
class CheckBoxButton: UIButton {
    public var isChecked: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if isChecked {
                setImage(checkedImg, for: [])
            } else {
                setImage(unCheckedImg, for: [])
            }
        }
    }
    private var unCheckedImg: UIImage!
    private var checkedImg: UIImage!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        guard let cImg = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.square"),
              let uImg = UIImage(systemName: "square")
        else {
            fatalError("Could not create check box images!!!")
        }
        
        self.unCheckedImg = uImg
        self.checkedImg = cImg

        setImage(unCheckedImg, for: [])
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let vStack = UIStackView()
        vStack.axis = .vertical
        vStack.spacing = 8
        
        for i in 0..<5 {
            let hStack = UIStackView()
            hStack.alignment = .center
            hStack.spacing = 8
            let label = UILabel()
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
            label.text = "Option \(i)"
            label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 28.0, weight: .light)
            let btn = CheckBoxButton()
            btn.backgroundColor = .white
            btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
            btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            hStack.addArrangedSubview(label)
            hStack.addArrangedSubview(btn)
            vStack.addArrangedSubview(hStack)
            hStack.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        
        vStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(vStack)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            vStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])

        // if we want to see the actual button frames...
        //  comment-out this return() line
        return()
        
        for hs in vStack.arrangedSubviews {
            if let hs = hs as? UIStackView,
               let btn = hs.arrangedSubviews.last as? CheckBoxButton
            {
                btn.backgroundColor = .yellow
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let btn = sender as? CheckBoxButton else { return }
        btn.isChecked.toggle()
    }
}


Can you recommend any UI element that's suitable for checkbox

@MacDeveloper - see the Edit to my answer.
